# Как реализовать нестандартный фон

Tags: css

Подскажите, как реализовать этот фон посредством СSS[image: Фон в точку]

Comment: А в чём проблема вставить его как картинку в background?

Answer (score 0):

Самым простым решением будет просто сохранить это изображение как файл. Задаёшь его как фон для `body` или создай лишний блок контейнер и задай фон для него.

```
body{
        background-image: url(test.png);
    }
```

Свойство `background-size` изменяет размер изображения. Если сделаешь изображение маленьким и остнанутся непокрытые области, то можно поставь `background-repeat: repeat`. (Хотя оно является значением по умолчанию и скорее всего тебе менять ничего не придётся)